# Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node, beacon-chain, goerli, beacon-nodes

Ethereum GOerli Network Sync stopped block number 7382822.
And one warning come (Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain! )

how to start sync in goerli network

Answer (score 5):

The Goerli network has now passed the Merge fork. In order to run a full node on Goerli, you need both an execution client like Geth and a consensus client like Prysm, Lighthouse, Nimbus, Teku or Lodestar.

That Merge was announced on [the Ethereum foundation blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/07/27/goerli-prater-merge-announcement).

I wrote 2 guides to run a full node on Goerli. You can use either one of them to resync from scratch. If you only want to have access to the network and use a web3 endpoint to do transactions, you don't need to do the validator client part or do a deposit.

- [Guide on how to join the Goerli/Prater merge testnet (Geth/Lighthouse)](https://github.com/remyroy/ethstaker/blob/main/merge-goerli-prater.md)
- [Guide on how to join the Goerli/Prater merge testnet (Besu/Teku)](https://github.com/remyroy/ethstaker/blob/main/merge-goerli-prater-alt.md)

Comment: I got this message when synchronizing the main network. Is there a way to do this for that network as well or is it a different thing for which I should ask a new question?

Comment: Is [this guide](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started#prerequisites) by geth.ethereum.org outdated? I' m getting " post-merge nw, but no beacon...looking 4 peers...dropping un-synced nodes..."

Comment: @Rémy  Any interest in answering https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/149267/how-to-get-enough-sepolia-eth-to-test-staking ?