# How to get enough Sepolia eth to test staking?

Tags: staking, faucets, sepolia

The Sepolia faucets prescribed here dispense a limited amount of eth each day. However, in order to test solo staking, one needs a non-trivial amount of eth. What is the most efficient way to procure enough eth for a solo staking setup so that multiple validation keys can be tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sepolia is a permissionned testnet which mean you cannot test solo staking there.

It's still possible to test solo staking on Goerli but getting the required Goerli ETH might be problematic. At [EthStaker](https://ethstaker.cc/), we have a `#cheap-goerli-validator` channel and process that can guide anyone from having zero Goerli ETH to performing the required Goerli validator deposits in a few minutes with a Discord account. Simply join the [EthStaker Discord](https://discord.io/ethstaker).

*This process will not get you any meaningful amount of Goerli ETH no matter what but you'll still end up with a full validator on Goerli. We also have minimal checks and delays in order to prevent abuses.*

Comment: What happens when Goerli is deprecated later this year? Where can one test solo staking then?

Comment: @tezette The plan is to move to a new network called Holešky (Holešovice Testnet) which is going to be permissionlesss like Goerli.

Comment: More testnets are being implemented to help with new stakers testing their setup before going on Mainnet. Ephemery is another testnet that can be used for that but it currently requires more efforts to use. We are working to help in making this easier for everyone.